# OSX Sandbox WKWebView Load Local File Inside

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview, appstore-sandbox

I have a WKWebView tied to an NSOpenPanel. I let the user select a file, but I am having trouble loading the file. When the app was not sandboxed I didn't have any problems, but once I turned on sandboxing I couldn't get it to work on OSX < 10.11. On OSX 10.11 I can use `webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: url)`, but it isn't available on < 10.11. What is the best way to load files from NSOpenPanel in a sandboxed osx swift app? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

- `NSURL` from your `NSOpenPanel` into `NSData` with `initWithContentsOfURL`
- then get a `NSString` out of this `NSData`
- then use

  ```
  WKWebView loadHTMLString(_ string: String,
      baseURL baseURL: NSURL?)
  ```

Comment: This will not work if the selected file causes the WKWebView to try to load any other resources from the local filesystem (such as images or scripts referenced in an HTML file).